# Can I Force Messaging.sendEmail to not be Successful in a Unit Test

Tags: unit-test, email

I have the following code in a class that I'd like to get coverage on.

```
    // Sends the email 
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] emailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

    for (Messaging.SendEmailResult r : emailResult) {
        if (!r.isSuccess()) {
            Messaging.SendEmailError[] errArr = r.getErrors();
            throw new EmailUtilException(errArr[0].getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I'd like to force the email to not send, but haven't been able to in my tests. If I provide an invalid email address, then the sendEmail line throws an error. I haven't been able to get it to execute the two lines inside the if loop. Is it possible to have sendEmail work and have the result fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the optional **allOrNothing** parameter on the [sendEmail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Messaging_sendEmail.htm) method, to avoid the exceptions and handle all errors yourself. This is typically used if your wanting to send some but not all messages sent in the list, so this workaround might not be what your looking for, but it does work...

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'bademail' });
mail.setReplyTo('support@acme.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Sender Display Name');
mail.setSubject('Subject');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Body');
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] emailResult = 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }, false);

System.assertEquals('Invalid to address : bademail', emailResult[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
```

Comment: Well, this would definitely let me get 100% code coverage! Not sure if it is exactly what I wanted to do. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: Did this help Daniel? I was thinking about it and since you already have the error handling code having additional errors reported reported through the same should not really be a big impact to you, unless you have a try/catch expecting to handle the other errors elsewhere? In some respects I kinda like all the errors being reported through the same approach, so could present an argument to use it even for a single item. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to go this route. The behavior of allOrNothing is not very intuitive in this case.

Comment: Yeah agree, in the DML case its one approach or another, in this case having some errors thrown and some returned muddies the waters a bit, not a great API design IMHO. Anyway glad i managed to help! :)

Comment: Old issue, but one that lives on. One thing to point out, and this may seem obvious, is that for this test to work, email deliverability needs to be enabled on org the test runs on.